# How to Convert FQL Result to List of Records.?

Tags: facebook-fql

I want to Convert my FQL Query result into the List of Records how I can Convert this my Query like this.

> "SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'Post_Id' "

I have converted into foreach loop but it will still not get desired result so my question is I want to list of comments of Post.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

```
FB.api({
          method: 'fql.query',
          query: 'SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id=\'' + POST_ID + '\''
       }, function(response) {
          alert(response.length);            
          if(response.length!=1) return; // bail out, no stream item found
          var comment_list = response[0].commment_list;
          for(var i=0; i<response[0].count; i++) {
             console.dir(comment_list[i]);
             alert('from: ' + comment_list[i].fromid + ' text: ' +  comment_list[i].text);
          }
       }
);
```

You can try it out for yourself at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/.  Just click on **Examples** and select "everyone-data" and change the query to be your SELECT, and then play with the code.